# Javascript Variable to PHP via AJAX (GET Method)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a Javascript variable to a PHP file using AJAX.

I have the below Javascript code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var route_id = 'travelling-from'; //Route ID

$('#'+route_id).change(function(e) {
    //Grab the chosen value on route change
    var selectroute = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'ajax-getvalues.php',
        data: { selectroute : selectroute }
    });
});
</script>
```

In my ajax-getvalues.php, I have;

```
$selectroute = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['travelling-from']);
```

When I try to use `$selectroute`, it seems to be empty.

Do I need to add something else in order for this to work? Or have I gone wrong at some point?

Comment: `selectroute` is the name that you're sending not `travelling-from`

Comment: also `GET` should be used to *get* data, use  `POST` to send data.

Comment: `POST` should be used when the client is sending data that will change the server's state (like a database update). `GET` may or may not be appropriate here as we have no idea what `ajax-getvalues.php` does.

Comment: @robbmj you're right, I somehow was assuming this would update session data but it may aswell be a simple search query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I try to use $selectroute, it seems to be empty

The AJAX request will be sent to `ajax-getvalues.php` with the query string:

```
?selectroute=somevalue
```

In PHP you are trying the get the value of a parameter called `travelling-from`, this parameter does not exist in the query string.

You need to change `selectroute` to `travelling-from`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'ajax-getvalues.php?travelling-from=' + encodeURIComponent(selectroute)
});
```

Or of you prefer:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'ajax-getvalues.php',
    data: {"travelling-from": encodeURIComponent(selectroute)}
});
```

This produces the query string `?travelling-from=somevalue` which can now be accessed with `$_GET['travelling-from']`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I added in the encodeURIComponent and I thought this had solved it but I am still having the same issue - it seems the selection value is being sent but not received by the PHP file - that is my guess anyway..?

Comment: @Sarah92 my answer addressed your original question (why you couldn't get the value of `travelling-from` in PHP). Since then you have modified the question such that you are not asking the same question any more. I suggest that you roll-back to the original question and start a new one for this new issue.

Comment: @Sarah92, you should undo the edit you made a few minutes ago as well.

Comment: how do I undo my edit as I do not have the original code I posted anymore?

Comment: @Sarah92, you can view the edit history and copy and paste from the previous version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72858/discussion-between-robbmj-and-sarah92).

Comment: The 'data' property does essentially the same including proper handling of the encoding, thus the above solution is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @SGD I am well aware of what the data property does, writing the answer in the manner that I did was an effort for the OP to realize the error.

Comment: @Sarah92, I have updated my answer with a more detailed explanation, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the key should be route_id instead of selectroute

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var route_id = 'travelling-from'; //Route ID

$('#'+route_id).change(function(e) { //Grab the chosen value on route change var selectroute = $(this).val();

var data = {};
data[route_id] = selectroute;
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'ajax-getvalues.php',
                data: data }
            }); </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - I tried this suggestion and had no luck. It seems the value is being sent but not received in the PHP file...:(

Comment: That's weird, just to be sure, you verified via console that that AJAX request is correct, right? But `$_GET['travelling-from']` should then do the trick on the PHP side of things. Is there any proxy or something in between which might swallow the HTTP param?

Comment: Your solution plainly does not work `route_id` is interpreted literally as the value `route_id` which would create a query string in the form of  `ajax-getvalues.php?route_id=somevalue`

Comment: Haha, you are of course right. I'll update the example.